# The Stanley Parable freezes after a few minutes of playing

Tags: steam, technical-issues, linux, the-stanley-parable

I just purchased the original *The Stanley Parable*, so I can try the game out for myself without having to... go on some sketchy website and download it.

After purchasing it, I installed the game, booted the game up, and it was playing fine, until a few minutes later when it suddenly froze. No error messages, it just crashes without a reason.

Trying to find out why it crashes, I ran Steam using the terminal, so I can see the log. But unfortunately, no error messages showed up when the game froze.

After some digging around on the Internet, I tried out a few workarounds like:

- Setting the game to a lower resolution
- Deleting the `bin/libstdc++.so.6`

But still, nothing changed. The game still freezes after few minutes of playing.

I'm guessing this is a problem with the Source engine that the original game was written in, because The Stanley Parable: Ultra Deluxe is built using Unity, and it launched and worked just fine, without any sort of issue.

Or it might just be because my computer is missing some weird dependencies which the game requires. I mean, it is a 9 years old game now, so maybe it's so old that it might need some patch. So what might  this problem be?

Information:

- Steam was installed from FlatHub

System information:

- Model: Dell 0R2XKN
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz
- OS: Freedesktop.org SDK 22.08 (Flatpak runtime) (64 bit)
- GPU: On-board Intel Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F)
- 8 GB RAM
- 500 GB SSD

Comment: The Ultra Deluxe version use Unity instead of Source.

Comment: Are you running it via Proton? Deleting `bin/libstdc++.so.6` is only recommended if you're running native, according to the ProtonDB page: https://www.protondb.com/app/221910

Comment: I'm running the game natively, and I've already tried deleting the file, but it did no help. Also I read that it's used to fix the game hang up on startup, not hang up after few minutes of playing

Comment: Does the game work if you play via Proton?

Comment: well yeah, it does work

Answer (score 1):

Per the question comments, OP confirmed the game runs if played via Proton

Comment: Upvoted, but this still does not explain the game's behaviour.

Comment: Agreed, the essential question appears to be, "Why does it freeze?" (phrased as, "So what might this problem be?"), though it's buried in the middle of the full question text.